# ¿Qué raíz es la que forma "comestible" o "bebestible"?

Tags: etimología, sufijos, latín

En La Tertulia [acabamos de descubrir](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41137160#41137160) que existe la palabra *bebestible*:

> [**bebestible**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5Gqznrv)
>   De beber<sup>1</sup>, formado a imit. de *comestible*.
>   1. adj. coloq. Que se puede beber. U. t. c. s.

Que hace referencia a:

> [**comestible**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9vcBo0L)
>   Del lat. tardío *comestibĭlis*.
>   1. adj. Que se puede comer.
>   2. m. Todo género de alimento. U. m. en pl.

(Apuntado para otra pregunta dejo el hecho de cuál sería su diferencia con [*bebible*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5GyjeTc) y [*comible*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9vn1Dn2))

Buscando en el DLE por *palabras que terminan en...* descubro que hay otras:

- [*digestible*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Dkpce8V)
- [*incomestible*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LGIwuiV)
- [*indigestible*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LOcnwYX) como sinónima de [*indigerible*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LOaiOtS)

Pero en ningún caso encuentro la raíz, más allá del *comestibĭlis* proviniente del latín en *comestible*. Así pues, ¿cuál es este sufijo? ¿Por qué se usa tan poco (apenas para tres verbos: *comer*, *beber* y *digerir*)?

Comment: Buscando palabras que terminan en "stible" salen algunas más: _adustible_ (que se puede adurir, esto es, abrasar o quemar), _combustible, incombustible, resistible, ustible_ (que se puede quemar). No estoy seguro de que en todos los casos sea el mismo sufijo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si te fijas, tanto *comestible* como *digestible* como *indigestible* tienen en común que provienen de palabras ya formadas en el latín tardío. El sufijo que tienen en común no es otro que *-ble*:

> **[-ble](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5gagNwr)**
>
> Del lat. -bĭlis.
>
> 1. suf. Forma adjetivos casi siempre deverbales. Indica posibilidad pasiva, es decir, capacidad o aptitud para recibir la acción del verbo. Si el verbo es de la primera conjugación, el sufijo toma la forma **-able**. *Prorrogable.* Si es de la segunda o tercera, toma la forma **-ible**. *Reconocible, distinguible.*

Es decir, lo que significa el sufijo es "que se puede". El truco está, como comentaba, en que esta palabra es la evolución de una palabra que ya existía en latín tardío. Como se puede ver en la definición de *comer*, esta viene de *comedĕre*. Así, al unirlo con la versión latina de *-ble* (*-bilis*) tendríamos *comedĕre* > *comedibĭlis* > *comestibĭlis* > *comestible*. Si el sufijo *-ble* lo aplicamos al verbo *comer* tal y como es actualmente, surge *comible*.

Por tanto, no es que el sufijo se use poco, sino que son pocas las palabras que nos han llegado con el sufijo ya aplicado a la versión latina de la palabra a la que modifica.