# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "comestible" y "comible"? ¿Y entre "bebestible" y "bebible"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, definiciones, significado, adjetivos

Al hilo de la pregunta [¿Qué raíz es la que forma "comestible" o "bebestible"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23202/1674) nos fijamos en que el DLE recoge estas duplas:

- comestible / comible
- bebestible / bebible
- digestible / digerible

Las definiciones son:

> [**bebible**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5GyjeTc)
>   De *beber*<sup>1</sup>.
>   1. adj. coloq. Dicho de un líquido: No del todo desagradable al paladar.
>
> [**bebestible**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5Gqznrv)
>   De *beber*<sup>1</sup>, formado a imit. de *comestible*.
>   1. adj. coloq. Que se puede beber. U. t. c. s.

Y:

> [**comible**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9vn1Dn2)
>   De *comer*<sup>1</sup> e *-ible*.
>   1. adj. coloq. Dicho de cosas de comer: Que no son enteramente desagradables al paladar.
>
> [**comestible**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9vcBo0L)
>   Del lat. tardío *comestibĭlis*.
>   1. adj. Que se puede comer.
>   2. m. Todo género de alimento. U. m. en pl.

Y finalmente el caso particular donde son directamente sinónimas:

> [**digestible**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Dkpce8V)
>   Del lat. tardío *digestibĭlis*.
>   1. adj. Que puede ser digerido.
>
> [**digerible**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Dkfv8Vh)
>   De *digerir* y *-ble*.
>   1. adj. [digestible](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Dkpce8V).

Tal y como comentó [Charlie en su respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23203/1674), el sufijo *-ble*...

> Forma adjetivos casi siempre deverbales. Indica posibilidad pasiva, es decir, capacidad o aptitud para recibir la acción del verbo

Pero claro, ¿qué diferencia hay entre que algo pueda comerse y que sea comible? ¿Una puñado de arena es comible pero no comestible, pues no aporta alimento? Y un vaso de cianuro, ¿es bebestible pero no bebible porque sienta algo mal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[**Fundéu**](http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/comible-y-comestible-no-significan-lo-mismo/)  nos da la respuesta:

> Comible es lo que no desagrada al paladar, mientras que comestible alude a lo que se puede ingerir sin que haga daño al organismo.

A esto agregan:

> De esta forma, cuando se dice que «Aunque esta seta es comestible, no es comible porque su sabor no es del todo agradable» se indica que la seta **se puede comer sin intoxicarse (comestible)**, pero el sabor resulta desagradable (no del todo comible).

Y agrego lo que puse en un comentario:

Las alcaparras o las aceitunas son *comestibles*. Pero en mi caso particular no son *comibles* porque me saben muy mal (no son agradables a mi paladar). Con esto diría que: lo comible es comestible, pero no todo lo comestible es comible. Lo comestible indica capacidad y lo comible gusto en hacerlo.

Comment: ¿Sería pues _comible_ algo subjetivo mientras que _comestible_ es bastante objetivo?

Comment: También pienso eso porque que algo sea comible/bebible o no dependerá de a quién se le pregunte y cuáles gustos tenga.